# Kio estas la diferenco inter "jako" kaj "mantelo"?

Tags: word-difference

Kiam mi lernis bazajn vortojn rilate al vestaĵoj, mi lernis "mantelo" sed ne "jako". Poste mi eltrovis ke "jako" estas ofte uzata kaj ke ĝi ne estas neologismo. Mi ĵus trarigardis la difinojn ĉe vortaro.net sed ankoraŭ ne komprenas la diferencon. Ĉu iu povas klarigi?

Ekzemple, el la vestaĵoj sur la bildoj, kiu(j) estas mantelo(j) kaj kiu(j) jako(j)?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Laŭ mia kompreno de la vortoj, nur B estas mantelo, dum A, C kaj D estas jakoj. Sed verŝajne estas unu el tiuj vortparoj, ĉe kiuj la limo ne estas tute klare difinita, kaj iom varias depende de la nacia lingvo, simile kiel ĉe "torto" kaj "kuko". Tamen ni ja strebu al unuecigo de la lingvouzo, kaj mi esperas, ke la voĉdonado por la diversaj proponataj respondoj donos bonan bildon pri tio, kiel homoj nuntempe komprenas la distingon.

Answer (score 3):

Jako estas malpli longa ol mantelo. Cetere, mantelo "kovras la aliajn vestojn" kaj ofte ŝirmas kontraŭ la vetero.

Laŭ mi, **A kaj B estas manteloj** kaj **C kaj D estas jakoj.**

Mi posedas vintran jakon por porti ekster la domon, sed ĝi estas malpli longa ol A.

Answer (score 1):

Laŭ la difinoj en PIV ŝajnas al mi ke jako tradicie estas vira vestaĵo kaj mantelo estas neseksigita. Same, jako havas specifan longecon “de la ŝultroj ĝis proks. la koksoj”, dum la priskribo de mantelo precipe nur diras, ke ĝi kovras aliajn vestaĵojn.

**Tial ŝajnas al mi, ke jako estas speco de mantelo.**